# Why Date field is not going to my Database column in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to store name, a start date and end date in my database. But when I submit the form the database is only taking the name but no Date is showing on the database. It is showing null.

**Model class:**

```
private String name;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/YYYY")
private Date startdate;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/YYYY")
private Date targetdate;
```

**Html form**

```
<form th:action="@{/saveTodo}" th:object="${todo}" method="POST">
<input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Todo" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
<br>
<input type="Date" th:field="*{startdate}" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
<br>
<input type="Date" th:field="*{targetdate}" placeholder="Target Date" class="form-control mb-4 col- 
4">
<br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save Todo</button>
</form>
```

**Controller class:**

```
@GetMapping("/showAddForm")
public String showAddForm(Model model) {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    model.addAttribute("todo", todo);
    return "AddTodo";
}

@PostMapping("/saveTodo")
public String saveTodo(@ModelAttribute("todo") Todo todo) {
    ts.saveTodo(todo);
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your controller and see what is inside your `todo` object? If time and date is available in your `todo` object, then show us your save `service` method and `repository` layer

Comment: @MortezaBandi I am only trying to store the date  not time. And I am giving the custom input to the form. But it is not reaching the database. here is my save and repository layer:

save Service:
    Override
    public void saveTodo(Todo todo) {
      tr.save(todo);
     }
Repository:
    Repository
    public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo, Integer>{
    }

Comment: I understood what you want. I want you to make sure that your desired value is inside your `todo` object when reaching your controller. Have you debugged your controller to see the inside of `todo`?

Comment: @MortezaBandi I have solved the problem by just changing input type="date" to "text" in html file. Now I have to write the whole date by my own. What's the actual problem here?

here is my HTML code: 

<input type="text" th:field="*{startdate}" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
 <br>
 <input type="text" th:field="*{targetdate}" placeholder="Target Date" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
 <br>

If I use "date" instead of text it does not work anymore.